# How to use "CMS Connect" in the LWR site?

Tags: experience-cloud, lwr, salesforce-cms, lightning-web-runtime

We are currently using third-party system like WordPress to fetch content to our website portal. We have plans to move forward building our site using LWR. But I do not see Content Management shown up in the Workspace.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [CMS Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/cms/guide/cms-connect-intro.html), this is only available in sites that are based on Customer Service, Partner Central, and Lightning Bolt solutions. So you won't be able to use this in an LWR site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CMS Workspaces in non-LWR and LWR sites. It is defined when you create the workspace

[image: Workspace Description]